# How do I add a custom field to the TFS 2010 sharepoint work item templates?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workitem

The manager was some specific fields added to the standard TFS web parts.. I could just make a Sharepoint List but then it would not haev a relation to the TFS bug/Task list..

So is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Team Explorer for that project.

Menu -> Tools -> Process Editor -> Work Items Types -> Open WIT from Server

From here, you can add additional fields and publish it back out.

Here is an article that will walk you through something similar to what you are trying to accomplish:

[Customization of TFS process template – adding field to a Work Item Definition](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/06/24/customization-of-tfs-process-template-adding-field-to-a-work-item-definition/)